# Using a non-static variable in a static method JAVA

Tags: java

So I am writing a very large java code, within this code I want it to output files in a particular file format. In this instance it is going to be a simple .txt file.

The data I am outputting is a series of coordinates, these coordinates have undergone rotation using an angle that is determined by the user prior to this code section.

The code to write the file is obviously in a static method but the angle I am calling is a non-static variable... how do I call this and get it to work?

Comment: Make the variable static or make an instance of the class the variable is in. Also, it's probably bad design to be implementing such a method as static in the first place but hey...

Answer (score 3):

Basically you have to pass an instance of the object containing the non-static variable to the static function and access it there.

That would look something like this:

```
public class ObjectToBeWritten {
  private int nonStaticVariable;

  public ObjectToBeWritten() {
      // ...
  }

  public int getNonStaticVariable() {
      return nonStaticVariable;
  }

  public static void outputToTxt(ObjectToBeWritten object) {
      nonStaticVariable = object.getNonStaticVariable();
      // ...
  }
}
```

Then you just call `ObjectToBeWritten.outputToTxt(object)` with the object that contains the non-static variable.

Answer (score 0):

Non static means that it belongs to some class instance(object). So pass this object to your static method and/or create those objects inside it.

Answer (score 0):

you should know non-static method belongs to Object ,but static method belongs to Class.Therefore the getNonStaticVariables method and nonStaticVariable should be static or  change the outputToTxt to non-static.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that perhaps either your non-static variable or your static method belong somewhere else.

When a class hold variable, non-static contents, it's probably a bad idea to provide static accessor functions that use that variable. I think the best solution is to separate the two, giving the responsibility of storing the mutable data in some Data Provider class that can provide a DEFENSIVE COPY of this variable. Perhaps you don't see the need for it because your example deals with a primitive value. But, if you were to change that to some object reference, you could run into all sorts of problems; one of which is that your code will not be thread-safe.

```
public class MyDataProvider {
  private Object nonStaticVariable;

  public MyDataProvider () {
    // ...
  }

  public Object getNonStaticVariable() {
    Object copy = new Object();
    // copy the internals from nonStaticVariable to copy
    return copy;
  }
}
```

Then, your utility class can use the copy of `nonStaticVariable` to do its work...

```
public class MyUtilityClass {
  public static void outputToTxt(Object nonStaticVariableCopy) {
    // do your work
  }
}
```

This solution solves all those problems and is much more robust:

1. Allows a non-static variable to be used by a static method
2. Your code will be thread-safe because you are using a copy of the non-static variable instead of the original variable.
3. Separation of concerns: Your utility class doesn't store any variables; thus all methods of the utility class can be static (like Java's `Math` class), and your Data Provider can be the container that holds your variables.